# iPhone app crashes at 2nd startup, when programmatically loading a ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

App crashes with error "Thread 1: signal SIGKILL" when I start it up the second time in the simulator. The first time it will work perfectly, but if I close the app completely (double tapping the home button and closing the app) and start it up again - it crashes.

I found others having the same problem (app crashes second time), but not of the same cause.

I tried creating a new project to isolate the error, and it happens when I'm trying to programmatically load a ViewController.

I have made two simple classes: MainView and Loader (which is supposed to load MainView).

In the viewDidAppear method in the Loader class I have the following code:

```
[super viewDidAppear:YES];

sleep(1); //Simulating to be doing stuff
MainView* mainView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainView"];
[self presentViewController:mainView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I get the following backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x9b5f5c22 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10, stop reason = signal SIGKILL
frame #0: 0x9b5f5c22 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
frame #1: 0x9b5f51f6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 70
frame #2: 0x0139b10a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186
frame #3: 0x012fe550 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1312
frame #4: 0x012fdd84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
frame #5: 0x012fdc9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #6: 0x012b07d8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 190
frame #7: 0x012b088a GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 103
frame #8: 0x00011626 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1163
frame #9: 0x00001c4d progLoadingTest`main + 141 at main.m:16
frame #0: 0x9b5f5c22 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
frame #1: 0x9b5f51f6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 70
frame #2: 0x0139b10a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186
frame #3: 0x012fe550 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1312
frame #4: 0x012fdd84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
frame #5: 0x012fdc9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #6: 0x012b07d8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 190
frame #7: 0x012b088a GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 103
frame #8: 0x00011626 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1163
frame #9: 0x00001c4d progLoadingTest`main + 141 at main.m:16
```

Comment: is there a backtrace available from your crash in Thread 1?  Also, when you "double tap the home button & close the app", are you *quitting* the app (via the "minus" icon that quits the app) or are you just going back into an already launched app?

Comment: Yes, i'm quitting it - should have been even more clear on that.
Can't find a backtrace (maybe i don't know where to find it?). The output window just says "(lldb)". The output window is showing "All Output".

Comment: You can type in something like "`bt 1`" at the "`(lldb)`" prompt and that should give you a backtrace for thread 1, if a backtrace exists for your crash.  If you get that, edit your question to show the backtrace and the code that leads up to it.

Comment: Answer updated with backtrace.

Comment: did you ever solve this?  if you set a breakpoint at start of those lines of code and step through those lines, where does the crash actually happen?

Comment: is there any add. console output? plz

Comment: Ok, I've looked in to it again. It seems to be normal behavior of any app that you close in the emulator and then start again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is normal behavior for any app that you close in the emulator and then start again in the emulator. I just coincidentally happened to be loading a ViewController. As such it really is not a crash.